# How to avoid the layout inflation each time a fragment transaction is committed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, fragment-oncreateview

I am using fragments to design my screen.
When I navigate back to another fragment (from the back stack), the **onCreateView(...)** method gets called each time even if the fragment has already been created.
How to avoid that the method **onCreateView(...)** gets called each time and make sure it's called only once (when it's created the first time)?

Comment: Can you include your fragment code in the post. Both, first and second fragments.

Answer (score 3):

You can cache your inflated view to the local field if your want. For example:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private View fragmentView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (fragmentView == null) {
            fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.you_super_view_id, container);
        }
        return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

But practically, it's ok that pager is reinflating views because it keeps only part of all fragments in memory at the time. So, I think the best idea is to let it work as it should